# Using ActiveX to Import from Excel to Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, import, activex, import-from-excel

I'm in need of optimizing import of .xls files to matlab due to xlsread being very time consuming with large amount of files. Current xlsread script as follows:

```
scriptName = mfilename('fullpath');
[currentpath, filename, fileextension]= fileparts(scriptName);    
xlsnames = dir(fullfile(currentpath,'*.xls'));
xlscount = length(xlsnames);
xlsimportdata = zeros(7,6,xlscount);

for k = 1:xlscount
xlsimport = xlsread(xlsnames(k).name,'D31:I37');
xlsimportdata(:,1:size(xlsimport,2),k) = xlsimport;
end
```

I have close to 10k files per week that needs processing and with approx. 2sec per file processed on my current workstation, it comes in at about 5½ hours.

I have read that ActiveX can be used for this purpose however that is far beyond my current programming skills and have not been able to find a solution elsewhere. Any help on how to make this would be appreciated.

If it is simple to perform with ActiveX (or other proposed method), I would also be interested in data on cells D5 and G3, which I am currently grabbing from 'xlsnames(k,1).name' and 'xlsnames(k,1).date'

EDIT: updated to reflect the solution

```
% Get path to .m script
scriptName = mfilename('fullpath');
[currentpath, filename, fileextension]= fileparts(scriptName);

% Generate list of .xls file data
xlsnames = dir(fullfile(currentpath,'*.xls'));
xlscount = length(xlsnames);
SampleInfo = cell(xlscount,2);
xlsimportdata = cell(7,6,xlscount);

% Define xls data ranges to import
SampleID = 'G3';
SampleRuntime = 'D5';
data_range = 'D31:I37';

% Initiate progression bar
h = waitbar(0,'Initiating import...');

% Start actxserver
exl = actxserver('excel.application');
exlWkbk = exl.Workbooks;

for k = 1:xlscount

    % Restart actxserver every 100 loops due limited system memory
    if mod (k,100) == 0
        exl.Quit
        exl = actxserver('excel.application');
        exlWkbk = exl.Workbooks;
    end

    exlFile   = exlWkbk.Open([dname filesep xlsnames(k).name]);
    exlSheet1 = exlFile.Sheets.Item('Page 0');

    rngObj1    = exlSheet1.Range(SampleID);
    xlsimport_ID = rngObj1.Value;

    rngObj2    = exlSheet1.Range(SampleRuntime);
    xlsimport_Runtime = rngObj2.Value;

    rngObj3    = exlSheet1.Range(data_range);
    xlsimport_data = rngObj3.Value;

    SampleInfo(k,1) = {xlsimport_ID};
    SampleInfo(k,2) = {xlsimport_Runtime};
    xlsimportdata(:,:,k) = xlsimport_data;

    % Progression bar updater
    progress = round((k / xlscount) * 100);

    importtext = sprintf('Importing %d of %d', k, xlscount);
    waitbar(progress/100,h,sprintf(importtext));
    disp(['Import progress: ' num2str(k) '/' num2str(xlscount)]);

end
%close actxserver
exl.Quit

% Close progression bar
close(h)
```

Comment: ActiveX will need also to open and close 10K files, I don't sure it will save time. if you can store the data in a fewer number of files, in separate sheets, it can much speed up both of methods. If not, consider this fex- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10465-xlswrite1

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that option available. The .xls files for import to matlab are automatically generated report files from 3rd party software running on workstations in production and lab.

Comment: You can save a lot of time by not opening and closing Excel every time you read a file as `xlsread` does. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/71199-opening-excel-only-once-at-the-beginning-of-the-optimization-proces-in-matlab-and-not-each-time-matl) for an example. Indeed this is done by directly operating the ActiveX agent. I had my own functions for this and more but I don't have them right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.  I am not an ActiveX Excel guru by any means.  However, this works for me for my small amount of test XLS files (3).  I never `close` the `exlWkbk`  so I don't know if memory usage is building or if it automatically cleaned up when descoped after the next is opened in its place ... so use at your own risk. I am seeing an almost 2.5x speed increase which seems promising.

```
>> timeit(@getSomeXLS)
ans =
    1.8641

>> timeit(@getSomeXLS_old)
ans =
    4.6192
```

Please leave some feedback if this work on large number of Excel sheets because I am curious how it goes.

```
function xlsimportdata = getSomeXLS()

scriptName = mfilename('fullpath');
[currentpath, filename, fileextension]= fileparts(scriptName);
xlsnames = dir(fullfile(currentpath,'*.xls'));
xlscount = length(xlsnames);
xlsimportdata = zeros(7,6,xlscount);
exl = actxserver('excel.application');

exlWkbk = exl.Workbooks;
dat_range = 'D31:I37';

for k = 1:xlscount
    exlFile   = exlWkbk.Open([currentpath filesep xlsnames(k).name]);    
    exlSheet1 = exlFile.Sheets.Item('Sheet1'); %Whatever your sheet is called.
    rngObj    = exlSheet1.Range(dat_range);
    xlsimport = cell2mat(rngObj.Value);
    xlsimportdata(:,:,k) = xlsimport;
end
exl.Quit
```

Comment: This solution is working excellent. Did a test with 100 files and found a 3.85x speed increase (177sec xlsread vs 46sec activex). I didn't encounter any memory usage issues. Ran the script on a i5-5300U with 8gb ram

Comment: I need to amend that comment. Memory usage increased continuously during importing so would need a solution for this if used for more than a few hundred files.

Comment: Maybe every 100 iterations or however many fit in memory call quit and restart the actxserver?  Like I said  im not 100% sure when memory is cleared but its worth a shot.  Inside the loop add something like `if mod (k,100) == 0`  exl.quit, etc.  Im on mobile so cant try anything now.

Comment: I made a similar implementation, although less elegant ;)

`relaunch = isa(k/100,'int32');
if relaunch == 1
exl.Quit
 exl = actxserver('excel.application');
exlWkbk = exl.Workbooks;`